# How to "unrotate" a div after partial rotation?

Tags: html, css, rotation, transition

Im rotating the text of this div and wondering how/if its possible to slowly unrotate the text once partially rotated and the mouse is moved from the div.

I cant target the div the mouse is moved onto because its not sure which div will be moved to.

Example is below.

http://jsfiddle.net/ofgyz7f7/

```
.reblogbutton{
position:relative;
display:table;
color:black;
width:60px;
height:60px;
border-radius:32px;
border: solid 2.5px black;
text-align:center;
margin:auto;
top:2.5px;
background-color:#B19CD9;


}

.reblogbutton a{
display:table-cell;
color:black;
vertical-align:middle;
}

.reblogbutton a:hover{
transform:rotate(360deg);
-o-transform:rotate(360deg);
-moz-transform:rotate(360deg);
-webbkit-transform:rotate(360deg);
    transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -webkit-transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -moz-transition: all 1.2s ease;
    -o-transition: all 1.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

something like this ?

http://jsfiddle.net/u197ymv9/

```
.reblogbutton a{
  display:table-cell;
  color:black;
  vertical-align:middle;
  transform:rotate(0deg);
  transition: all 1.2s ease;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you mean to revert anti-clock-wise? If so, you'd need to specify the desired effect to the default state. I'm using something saimilar to animate my logo. The CSS goes like so:

```
#logo {
    width: 3.000em;
    height: 3.000em;
    float: right;
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(-360deg);
}

#logo:hover {
    transition: transform 0.5s;
    transform: rotate(360deg);
}
```

The result is on my site at phclaus.eu.org (sorry for the self-promo)